# I get 'No more data to read from socket' after a period of inactivity. Weblogic and Oracle DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, weblogic

I have a JSP web application deployed on a Weblogic server connected to an Oracle Database. There is no datasource set in the weblogic server instance and the application communicates with the database on it's own (with jdbc). However, every morning when I try to access the web page I get a 'No more data to read from socket' error. I reset the weblogic server and everything gets back to normal, but the thing is I can't keep restarting the server every morning. 
Is there anyway that this can be fixed automatically? I think it has something to do with the connections in the pool, probably being disabled by oracle but still considered active by the application...

Thanks

Comment: you have identified it right, this message 'No more data to read from socket' means that the socket was closed by one of the parties in this case possibly oracle DB. The way to resolve this would be to periodically poll the JDBC connection, better still if you could revert to using wls connection pooling.

Comment: Thanks SridharS. I did create a weblogic jdbc datasource for my deployment and still got the same error this morning :( Can you advice how to poll the connection now that I use the datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to get this corrected.

What I did was creating a datasource in the Weblogic admin console and then configure my app to use this datasource. It was still giving the error initially but then I unchecked the "Keep Connection After Local Transaction" box from the datasource transaction options and this fixed the problem.