# No data read from socket and Internal 500 error

Tags: java, sockets, oracle11g, weblogic11g, solaris-10

I have a web application I deployed to WebLogic 10.3.6 on a Solaris machine and Oracle database 11.2.0.1. I created a datasource in weblogic and tested it, which was successful. I deployed the web application and logged in to the application. This should validate the user thru the DB and fetch some summary info but from every screen it shows query failed `Internal 500` error. And in the weblogic console it says `No more data read from socket`.

Trace Log:

```
Exception raised =No more data to read from socket
[2015 Aug26 23:42:26:553]java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3593)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3637)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:135)
```

DB Oracle 11.2.0.1

JDK 1.7.0.60

Weblogic 10.3.6

Comment: Sounds like your DB connection is stale. See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386621/i-get-no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-after-a-period-of-inactivity-weblogic or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839907/no-more-data-to-read-from-socket-error

Comment: Any resolution to this issue. I'm running Oracle DB 11.2.0.4/JDK 1.7.0.79/WL 10.3.6 and having the same issue?